# How can I create relationships to all neighbors of a match?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to build a sparse time tree in my db:

```
MATCH (m:Month)-[:HAS_YEAR]->(y:Year)
WITH m, y ORDER by y.year, m.month
RETURN collect(m)
```

I would like to add a `-[:FOLLOWS]->` relationship between Month nodes following each others. Is there a simple way to loop through the list of nodes and create these relationships?

Notes:

- by sparse, I mean that some month nodes are missing if no test got conducted that month. For example, we have `(y:Year(number: 2019})<-[:HAS_YEAR]-(:Month{number: 4})<-[:FOLLOWS]-(:Month{number: 6})-[:HAS_YEAR]->(y)`.
- For context, I have a list of `(:Test)` nodes with a date field, which I parsed to create the relationship `(:Test)-[:DONE_ON]->(:Month)`. And I'm trying to find a good way to filter the list of tests done in the last recorded month (whether it is this month, the previous one or an older one). If using Month nodes, I could simply query `MATCH (t:Test)-[:DONE_ON]->(m:Month) WHERE NOT EXISTS (m)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(:Month) RETURN t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you have APOC Procedures installed, and you're satisfied with the sorting, then the collect() will keep them in sorted order. You can then use `CALL apoc.nodes.link(list, 'FOLLOWS')` and it will create those relationships between all nodes in the list.